# Why is my card layout opening multiple windows?

Tags: java, swing, window, cardlayout

I'm trying to make a game in Java, and games have menus. Menus need to be operated and will lead to more screens. I've looked into using a card layout to switch between panels and it works, except every time it switches panel, it opens it in a new window along with a blank panel. What I want to know is why is it opening in new windows and why is it opening a blank panel?

Creating the card layout:

```
public static CardLayout cards = (CardLayout)pnlMaster.getLayout();

getContentPane().add(pnlMaster);

    pnlMaster.add(pnlMain, "Main Menu");
    pnlMaster.add(pnlOptions, "Options");
    pnlMaster.add(pnlGame, "Game");

    cards.show(pnlMaster, "Main Menu");
```

And this is run when the options button is clicked:

```
public class Options 
{
JPanel pnlMain = Window.pnlMain;
JPanel pnlOptions = Window.pnlOptions;
JPanel pnlMaster = Window.pnlMaster;

Button graphics = Window.btnGraphics;

public Options()
{
    Listener listener = new Listener();

    pnlOptions.add(graphics);

    Window.cards.show(pnlMaster,"Options");

    graphics.addActionListener(listener);
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Window` and why do you need another instance of it?

Comment: Window is the class which extends JFrame. It was part of an old method (instead of cards) I tried to use and is now of no use. I've removed it and the program behaves the same.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's a shame I can't vote up comments because that was basically answering my problem with your question. Thanks.